# Compile time comparison between Windows GCC and MSVC compiler

Tags: windows, visual-studio, gcc, compiler-construction

We are working on reducing compile times on Windows and are therefore considering all options. I've tried to look on Google for a comparison between compile time using GCC (MinGW or Cygwin) and MSVC compiler (CL) without any luck. Of course, making a comparison would not be to hard, but I'd rather avoid reinventing the wheel if I can.

Does anyone know of such an comparison out there? Or maybe anyone has some hands-on-experience?

Input much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Comparing compiler is not trivial:

- It may vary from processor to processor. GCC may better optimize for i7 and MSVC for Core 2 Duo or vice versa. Performance may be affected by cache etc. (Unroll loops or don't unroll loops, that is the question ;) ).
- It depends very largely on how code is written. Certain idioms (equivalent to each other) may be preferred by one compiler.
- It depends on how the code is used.
- It depends on flags. For example gcc `-O3` is known to often produce slower code then `-O2` or `-Os`.
- It depends on what assumption can be made about code. Can you allow strict aliasing or no (`-fno-strict-aliasing`/`-fstrict-aliasing` in gcc). Do you need full IEEE 754 or can you bent floating pointer calculation rules (`-ffast-math`).
- It also depends on particular processor extensions. Do you enable MMX/SSE or not. Do you use intrinsics or no. Do you depend that code is i386 compatible or not.
- Which version of gcc? Which version of msvc?
- Do you use any of the gcc/msvc extensions?
- Do you use microbenchmarking or macrobenchmarking?

And at the end you find out that the result was less then statistical error ;)

Even if the single application is used the result may be inconclusive (function A perform better in gcc but B in msvc).

PS. I would say cygwin will be slowest as it has additional level of indirection between POSIX and WinAPI.

Comment: The question is about compilation times, not about performance of the resulting executable.

Comment: Nearly all of the above apply as well except possibly the last one to measuring the compiler speed.